# Django model design - How to handle multiple optional attributes?

Tags: python, django, database-design

I'm a novice in Django (but an experienced developer), and I'm starting to build my first Django project.

The project is really simple: a website where people can join events. An administrator sets an sports event, chooses the date, the kind of event (running, tennis match, bycicle ride), etc, and users can join it.

My problem is that the events can have very different data inside, depending on his category. For example, if it's a two-people team tennis match, an users should enter his name and his teammate name, their team name, etc. If the event is a bycicle ride, he can choose if he wants the difficult or the easy route, etc.

I know I can create a big model with all the attributes for every kind of event, but this is a really ugly design... There should be a common table for all registrations, with a link to the event and the basic and common data (name, address, phone, email, etc), but I don't know how to handle the specific data for each sport/event category... Any idea about how to organize this in Django models? Maybe adding a simple `(key, inscription_id, type, value)` table? And then, how can I render the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you suggested is called `Entity-attribute-value` model

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model

I think there could be a good argument for keeping all data belonging to your events defined inside of a model instead of through a related generic EAV table.

To do this you could use one of django's polymorphic libraries.  I have used [django-model-utils' InheritanceManager](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/managers.html#inheritancemanager) in production.  There are quite a few libraries including django-polymorphic.

Taking an inhertance based approach you might define a single `Event` model or `Sport` model.  A sport might have a name, league, etc. All `Event`s might have a start date and end date and sport.

Using this approach you can defined foriegn keys from your registrations to the base `Event` class and use djangos built in ORM to select all events or registrations of certain types, without having the additional application logic/object inspection/ property inspection of taking an EAV approach!

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I'm looking for! As I'm a complete Django novice, I didn't know it was possible to have model inheritance (like in Hibernate, as far as I remember). Very good answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can store all additional data in Text field using JSON object or other serializer.

Take look at [django-jsonfield](https://github.com/bradjasper/django-jsonfield)

Comment: How do you query on the data in the jsonfield?

Comment: It's only possible using regex or built into database functionality to parse json (if any). But if you don't have to query by that data, just display it, you can use it.

Comment: As dm03514 says, adding all the data in a JSON field limits the capabilities of the database, like searching for all the registered users who want to play tenis in a grass field (for example)... Anyway, thank you for your answer! :)